# trouble selecting data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I just want to select and display data from a database. I think I am following all the tutorials etc. online but something is wrong. My code:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db='test';
$host ='localhost';
$name = 'ryan';


$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
    else{
        echo 'Checkpoint 1 <br>';
    }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE ryan";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
echo'checkpoint 2';
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo'checkpoint 3';
?>
```

I can get to 'checkpoint 2' but for some reason the fetch_assoc() function does not do anything. I am using Netbeans, and the fetch_assoc() does not even turn green as the num_rows function does. fetch_assoc does turn green if I remove both parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE 'ryan'";
```

Comment: you sir are a genius, this worked perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ratrace123 You can also use this query for wildcard search `$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%ryan%'";`

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql query syntax is wrong.
[`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) takes a pattern, by not enclosing it in quotes, you basically provided a column name

Change your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name` LIKE 'ryan';
```

Also add some error handling for the query

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli->error);
```

Comment: this also worked, maybe i got lucky when i used mysql keywords w/o the back ticks.

Comment: Points 1 and 2; they don't need to be escaped with backticks, as they are not reserved words, they're only keywords. There are no `(R)` next to those functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks, edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your like statement as

```
$param = "%ryan%";
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE ?");
$result->bind_param("s", $param);
$result->execute();
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: is there a benefit in binding a prepared statement each time vs just asking straight as I have done without binding first?

Comment: Bind statement is secure and prevent you form sql injection!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db='test';
$host ='localhost';
$name = 'ryan';


$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
    else{
        echo 'Checkpoint 1 <br>';
    }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE 'ryan'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
print_r($num_results);exit;
echo'checkpoint 2';
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo'checkpoint 3';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string input with `LIKE` statement by using the `quotes` and `%` sign.

**Modified Code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%ryan%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

**What i have changed?**

1. Add single quotes inside the double quote for input string.
2. Add % sign at start and end for matching type both